# Bidirectional One-To-Many-relation between two (table-per-class)-inheritance trees

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many, table-per-class

**ABSTRACT**

Say, I have two simple @Entity inheritance trees (one abstract base class with two concrete implementation classes in each tree) of InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS; and I need a bidirectional @OneToMany relation connecting the base classes using a @JoinColumn.

This should produce *four* tables, one per concrete class, right? EclipseLink produces a fifth table for one of the abstract base classes which does not make sense to me. Consider this example (this is not a real-world example; it is just about JPA):

**EXAMPLE**

Collection is the abstract root of the first inheritance tree and implementor of the @OneToMany relation:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Collection {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="collection")
    public List<Media> items = new ArrayList<Media>();
}
```

PhysicalCollection and VirtualCollection are concrete implementations of Collection:

```
@Entity
public class PhysicalCollection extends Collection {}

@Entity
public class VirtualCollection extends Collection {}
```

Media is the abstract root of the second inheritance tree and implementor of the @ManyToOne relation:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Media {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    public Collection collection;
}
```

CdMedia and TapeMedia are concrete implementations of Media:

```
@Entity
public class CdMedia extends Media {}

@Entity
public class TapeMedia extends Media {}
```

**RESULT**

As I said, EclipseLink will produce *five* tables from this (don't mind the SEQUENCE table):

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_test     |
+--------------------+
| CDMEDIA            |
| MEDIA              |
| PHYSICALCOLLECTION |
| SEQUENCE           |
| TAPEMEDIA          |
| VIRTUALCOLLECTION  |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the unexpected table MEDIA will have a useless definition (the foreign key target changes semantics when renaming PhysicalCollection):

```
CREATE TABLE `MEDIA` (
    `COLLECTION_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    KEY `FK_MEDIA_COLLECTION_ID` (`COLLECTION_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_MEDIA_COLLECTION_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`COLLECTION_ID`) REFERENCES PHYSICALCOLLECTION` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. Are my expectiations correct? (Create 4 tables, not 5)
2. Can someone confirm that this is a bug in EclipseLink?
3. If not a bug, can you point out where I make a mistake?

Comment: i have a similar model and the same issue. did you managed to workaround it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TABLE_PER_CLASS should not be creating a table for any abstract class, so that is a bug.  It is very odd you don't also get a table for Collection?  Are you sure MEDIA is abstract, did you miss recompiling/deploying your code?

I know this bug existed in EclipseLink 2.0, but think it was fixed after that, so you may want to try the latest version, otherwise log a bug.

In general I would not recommend TABLE_PER_CLASS, especially in this model where you have a lot of realtionships.  It would be much better to use SINGLE_TABLE or JOINED inheritance.

Comment: Yes, rest assured, I checked recompilation and caching issues multiple times ;).

Comment: Obviously, MEDIA is created because it defines the @JoinColumn (which makes no sense) and cannot use the underlying DBs for foreign key constraints since it tries to reference an abstract class; it therefore erroneously maps to some concrete subtype (which is nearly criminal ;).

Comment: In the meanwhile, I found out there is someone else having this issue [http://www.verious.com/qa/jpa-one-to-many-using-inheritance/] and obviously eclipselink does currently (v2.4.0) not provide this feature.

Comment: Anyway, the JPA implementation should throw a runtime exception if it does not support TABLE_PER_CLASS reliably - or at least throw a runtime exception when the problem situation arises.